# Creating version 1.5 PDFs instead of version 1.7 PDFs from CR2010

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports

Crystal Reports 2010 on VS2010 is creating PDF files with the property: version set to 1.7.
Is there a way to create PDF files with file version 1.5?

Comment: Can you tell me what the reason is that you want to set the version to 1.7? Do you want to force CR to not generate features that were introduced after 1.5 or are you concerned about PDF readers that do not support 1.7?

Comment: Client still has an old version of acrobat reader (version 6) and message is being displayed when a pdf document (version 1.7) is opened. This is not appending when e edit the PDF in (hexadecimal), change the 1.7 to 1.5, save it and open it on the old acrobat reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a way to modify this behaviour within the Crystal runtime engine. You should use an older runtime engine if you want to go back.