# Crystal Report of Exported PDF version

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Currently I am using Crystal report 11 to generate reports in PDF format.
The version in which PDF's are generated in 1.3

I would like to upgrade the PDF version to 1.4 (For ISO Document).

Could anyone please advise me what is the way forward on this?

Comment: No luck with my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answers below, it looks like you will need to upgrade the version of Crystal Reports you are using or use some other program to convert the PDF. It appears that Crystal Report does not have a setting for PDF Version.

- [Creating version 1.5 PDFs instead of version 1.7 PDFs from CR2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160795/creating-version-1-5-pdfs-instead-of-version-1-7-pdfs-from-cr2010)
- http://scn.sap.com/thread/2093502
- [Exporting RPT to PDF version 1.3 in Crystal Reports 10.5.3700](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397564/exporting-rpt-to-pdf-version-1-3-in-crystal-reports-10-5-3700)
- http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Reporting_/Crystal_Reports/Q_25349902.html

Other solutions:

- http://www.nicepdf.com/products.html
- http://en.softonic.com/s/pdf-version-converter-2.01